# remove content after </html> using dreamweaver find & replace

Tags: dreamweaver, replace

i need to remove content after  using dreamweaver find & replace in multiple files (different content). how can i do that?. will regular expression solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution
Find box give  `</html>+[^]*`
Replace box `</html>`